# add a value to an external link query in searchform

Tags: php, functions

I have a little issue with an imported searchform in wordpress. 
We have imported the searchform here: http://www.campingsosflores.com/en/
All the code is running inside a wordpress plugin.

[image: searchform]

using the following code:

```
    <?php

    function netbooking_searchform($content){

        $GLOBALS["content"] = $content;

        // Function to read a default value in case of error 
        $INPUT = function($param, $default = "", $prefix = true){
            $key = $prefix ? 'netbooking_searchbox_'.$param : $param;
            return isset($GLOBALS["content"][$key]) ? $GLOBALS["content"][$key] : $default;
        };

        $language = $INPUT('language', 'it', false);
        $lang = substr($language, 0, 2);
        $cryptedID = $INPUT('crypted_id', 'OiAmpE15aWU=', false);
        $mod = $INPUT('mod', 'v', false);

        // Search form sections to be shown
        $displayOptions = array();
        $displayOptions['show_arrival_date'] = "#datefromlabel {display:none;} #datefromvalue {display:none;}";
        $displayOptions['show_departure_date'] = "#datetolabel {display:none;} #datetovalue {display:none;}";
        $displayOptions['show_number_of_persons'] = "#numpeoplelabel {display:none;} #numpeoplevalue {display:none;}";
        $displayOptions['show_type'] = "#structuresnameslabel {display:none;} #structuresnamesvalue {display:none;}";

        // Create CSS using parameters from the form 
        $css = "";
        foreach ($displayOptions as $key => $option) {
            $toShow = $INPUT($key, "on");
            if (isset($toShow) && $toShow != "on"){
                $css .= $option;
            }
        }

$customlabel = 'Bambini (4 - 10 anni)';

if ($lang == 'en') $customlabel = "Children (4 - 10 Years)"; // Language String for label



        // Get searchform HTML from WebService
        $api = 'https://webserverlink.com/p/'.$cryptedID.'/it/index.php';
        $query = http_build_query([
            'type' => 'p',
            'returnmod' => 'xml',
            'id' => $cryptedID,
            'cmd' => 'searchform',
            'l' => substr($language, 0, 2),
            'mask' => '1111110',
            'mod' => $mod,
            'lblchildren'=> $customlabel,
            **'age_1' => '4',** // THE ISSUE IS HERE: This is not added to the link when I click on submit button
            'nocss' => '0'

        ]);
        $searchform_html = file_get_contents($api. '?' . $query );
        $searchform_html = utf8_decode($searchform_html);
        // DOM Parsing
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($searchform_html);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $booking = $dom->getElementById('booking'); 
        //$booking->removeChild($booking->firstChild); // ... #booking has a first child we don't know about...

        // Utility Fuction
        $appendAttribute = function($dom, $element, $attribute_name, $value){
            $attribute = $dom->createAttribute($attribute_name);
            $attribute->value = $value;
            $element->appendChild($attribute);
        };
        $createStyleElement = function($dom, $css_str) {
            $appendAttribute = function($dom, $element, $attribute_name, $value){
                $attribute = $dom->createAttribute($attribute_name);
                $attribute->value = $value;
                $element->appendChild($attribute);
            };
            $style_node = $dom->createElement('style', $css_str);
            $appendAttribute($dom, $style_node, 'type', 'text/css');
            return $style_node;
        };
        $createLinkElement = function($dom, $url) {
            $appendAttribute = function($dom, $element, $attribute_name, $value){
                $attribute = $dom->createAttribute($attribute_name);
                $attribute->value = $value;
                $element->appendChild($attribute);
            };
            $link_node = $dom->createElement('link');
            $appendAttribute($dom, $link_node, 'rel', 'stylesheet');
            $appendAttribute($dom, $link_node, 'type', 'text/css');
            $appendAttribute($dom, $link_node, 'href', $url);
            return $link_node;
        };

        // New styles to add
        //$defaultStyle = $createStyleElement($dom, $cssOptions['default']);
        $cssCleanerStyle = $createLinkElement($dom, "http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset-context/cssreset-context-min.css");
        $customStyle = $createStyleElement($dom, $css);
        $googleFontsLink = $createLinkElement($dom, "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya|Alegreya Sans|Anonymous Pro|Archivo Narrow|Arvo|BioRhyme|Bitter|Cabin|Cardo|Chivo|Cormorant Garamond|Crimson Text|Domine|Eczar|Fira Sans|Gentium Basic|Inconsolata|Karla|Lato|Libre Baskerville|Libre Franklin|Lora|Merriweather|Montserrat|Neuton|Old Standard TT|Open Sans|PT Sans|PT Serif|Playfair Display|Poppins|Rajdhani|Raleway|Roboto|Roboto Slab|Rubik|Source Sans Pro|Source Serif Pro|Space Mono|Work Sans");
        $netbookingStyle = $booking->firstChild;
        $booking->removeChild($booking->firstChild); // remove to add later

        // styles added from last to first (cause only "insertBefore" exist here...)
        $toInsert = [$googleFontsLink, $customStyle, $netbookingStyle, /*$defaultStyle, */$cssCleanerStyle];
        foreach ($toInsert as $element) {
            $booking->insertBefore($element, $booking->firstChild);
        }

?>


    <div class="yui3-cssreset mod<?= $mod;?>">
        <?= $dom->saveHTML();?>
    </div>

<?php };

?>
```

**'age_1' => '4',** // THE ISSUE IS HERE: This value is not added to the link when I click on submit button.

Someone could help me to understand where I'm wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Solved simly adding a js inside the plugin to create the valu age_1